# Add Header to CSV export in PHP

Tags: php, csv

I'm trying to export my data into a CSV in PHP after running some queries on it. So far, I'm able to successfully to do so using:

```
   $temp = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
   $fp = fopen("results.csv", "w");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   fputcsv($fp, $row);
   }

   fclose($fp);
```

However, I don't understand how to keep the headers that my SQL query forms.

Comment: Just simply print the field names as the 1st row.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The basics is, just insert the first row as your headers manually

```
   $temp = mysqli_query($link, $sql);
   $fp = fopen("results.csv", "w");

   fputcsv($fp, array("Header 1", "Header 2", "Header 3");

   while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
   fputcsv($fp, $row);
   }

   fclose($fp);
```

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but something like this:

```
$added_headers = false;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
    if(!$added_headers) {
        fputcsv($fp, array_map(function($field) {return $field->name;}, mysqli_fetch_fields($temp)));
        $added_headers = true;
    }
    fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First get the query columns as headers. Put them to csv once before putting the data.

```
$flag = 0; // define a flag to check if header is printed to csv file
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($temp, MYSQLI_ASSOC)){
 if(!flag){ // if header is not added
    $header =  array_keys($row);
    fputcsv($fp, $header); // add header to csv file
    $flag = 1; // update the flag 
  }
  fputcsv($fp, $row);
}
```

Not tested but at least it gives some idea.